# How do I recover a deleted file from an SD card?

Tags: sd-card, file-recovery

We have deleted a file by mistake, and now I don't know how to recover them.

How do I recover files from an SD card?

Comment: First rule of data recovery: If you *Really* want the data, contact a data recovery company.

Comment: Yes it is, but any more specific answer you'll get will recommend recovery software, and this site is not for software recommendations. Conflict ;-) I suggest you Google "photo recovery"

Comment: @JanDoggen | Since the question was not asking specifically for software it could be a case the OP isn't sure if there is a method without software. Just in case anyone was going to penalize for this point.

Answer (score 1):

Boot a Linux live system.
Insert the card, but don't mount it (linux will ask you).
Install and run testdisk, there's about a million tutorials about how to use it.
Restore your data to another drive.

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming you didn't delete them from a computer (in which case check your recycle bin) then you should be able to use a file recovery program like  [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) or any other one you might have a preference for.

Stick your card in the computer and run the recovery program on the card. See what it comes up with. If it doesn't find the files you want there isn't a lot you can do about it.